# Expo Push notification Encountered an exception while calling native method

Tags: expo, expo-notifications

I Created an expo app with expo notification but i got an error my app(apk) with this. i followed the expo documentation from setting up firebase to adding server key to my credentials on expo account but i always get this

Encountered an exception while calling native method: Exception occurred while executing exported method getDevicePushTokenAsync on module ExpoPushTokenManager: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process

but if im using expo go it works perfectly